# How do I get data from a subprocess PIPE while the subprocess is running in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, subprocess, qthread

I've got a program on Windows that calls a bunch of subprocesses, and displays the results in a GUI.  I'm using PyQt for the GUI, and the `subprocess` module to run the programs.

I've got the following `WorkerThread`, that spawns a subthread for each shell command devoted to reading the process *stdout* and printing the results (later I'll wire it up to the GUI).

This all works.  *Except* `proc.stdout.read(1)` *never* returns until after the subprocess has completed.  This is a big problem, since some of these subprocesses can take 15-20 minutes to run, and I need to display results as they're running.

What do I need to do to get the pipe working while the subprocess is running?

```
class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        def sh(cmd, cwd = None):
            proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                    shell = True,
                                    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,
                                    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                                    cwd = cwd,
                                    env = os.environ)

            proc.stdin.close()

            class ReadStdOutThread(QtCore.QThread):
                def run(_self):
                    s = ''
                    while True:
                        if self.request_exit: return

                        b = proc.stdout.read(1)
                        if b == '\n':
                            print s
                            s = ''
                            continue

                        if b:
                            s += b
                            continue

                        if s: print s
                        return

            thread = ReadStdOutThread()
            thread.start()

            retcode = proc.wait()
            if retcode:
                raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

            return 0
```

FWIW: I rewrote the whole thing using `QProcess`, and I see the exact same problem.  The `stdout` receives no data, until the underlying process has returned.  Then I get everything all at once.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how long will be the the lines of command's output you can poll on the stdout PIPE of the process.

An example of what I mean:

```
import select
import subprocess
import threading
import os

# Some time consuming command.
command = 'while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo "Testing"; done'

# A worker thread, not as complex as yours, just to show my point.
class Worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(
            command, shell=True, 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
        )

    def run(self):
        self.proc.communicate()


    def get_proc(self):
        # The proc is needed for ask him for his
        # output file descriptor later.
        return self.proc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Worker()
    w.start()

    proc = w.get_proc()

    pollin = select.poll()

    pollin.register(proc.stdout, select.POLLIN)


    while ( 1 ):
        events = pollin.poll()
        for fd, event in events:
             if event == select.POLLIN:
                 # This is the main issue of my idea,
                 # if you don't know the length of lines
                 # that process ouput, this is a problem.
                 # I put 7 since I know the word "Testing" have
                 # 7 characters.
                 print os.read(fd, 7)
```

Maybe this is not exactly what you're looking for, but I think it give you a pretty good idea of what to do to solve your problem.

**EDIT**: I think I've just found what you need [Streaming stdout from a Python subprocess in Python](https://gist.github.com/mattbornski/3299031).

Comment: I don't know how long the output will be.

Comment: @ChrisB. I just added a link to an example it might be that your are looking for.